# Query to select worst-selling products

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, group-by

I have these 3 tables/classes in the Entity Framework model:

```
Orders (OrderedItems, OrderTime)
OrderedItems (Product, Qty)
Products (Name, CreatedTime)
```

I can select the best-selling products by doing this

```
var items = Orders.SelectMany(o => o.OrderedItems);
var products = items.GroupBy(oi => oi.Product)
                    .OrderByDescending(g => g.Sum(oi => oi.Qty))
                    .Select(g => g.Key).Take(10);
```

How do I select the worst-performing products (ie. the opposite)?

Note: **Worst-performing products may not exists in the Orders table** because they may never be ordered.

Comment: You just need to invert your ordering.. you're using `OrderByDescending` at the moment.. change it to `OrderBy`.

Comment: It won't get products that are never ordered. I have made the last line bold.

Comment: Yes I also want to get the products that are not in the Orders table, by common sense

Comment: Are you by any chance storing this data in SQL? Because this is a case where I would probably use a stored procedure to pull the data...

Comment: I've been too spoiled with LINQ and forgot about stored procs. Thanks a lot for all your comments Leon you understood the question the best!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start with the `Products` table and find matches from there.  One way is to use the [join into](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311040.aspx) clause to group join the `Products` table with the `OrderedItems`:

```
var items = Orders.SelectMany(o => o.OrderedItems);
var products = (from product in Products
                join item in items on product equals item.Product into matchingItems
                orderby matchingItems.Sum(oi => oi.Qty)
                select product).Take(10);
```

Another way, which is probably less efficient but you might find more readable, is to filter the items using `Enumerable.Where()`:

```
var items = Orders.SelectMany(o => o.OrderedItems);
var products = (from product in Products
                orderby items.Where(oi => oi.Product == product).Sum(oi => oi.Qty)
                select product).Take(10);
```

This translates nicely into method syntax:

```
var items = Orders.SelectMany(o => o.OrderedItems);
var products = Products.OrderBy(p => items.Where(oi => oi.Product == product)
                                          .Sum(oi => oi.Qty))
                       .Take(10);
```

Comment: This still doesn't address their issue of items that don't appear in the order table. This will only select items that exist in orders.

Comment: @LeonNewswanger All I'm doing is ordering the Products table.  There is no filtering, so Products with no items will be included.

Comment: Sorry I stand corrected. I skimmed over your code too quickly. My apologies. This should absolutely work now that I took a second look. +1 for you.

Comment: @LeonNewswanger: I appreciate your concern.  I would much rather have someone question my answer than have an error that nobody mentions.

Comment: Brilliant! I can't believe it is so simple!

Answer (score 2):

```
var items = Orders.SelectMany(o => o.OrderedItems);
var products = items.GroupBy(oi => oi.Product)
                    .OrderBy(g => g.Sum(oi => oi.Qty))
                    .Select(g => g.Key).Take(10);
```

Comment: This won't get Products that are never ordered

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
OrderBy(g => g.Sum(oi => oi.Qty))
```

it will put minimum sums first.

Comment: It won't get Products that are never ordered

Comment: @aximili: Then first filter `Where(p => p.Qty > 0)`

Comment: Sorry I don't understand. When selecting the best-selling, I can get the products ordered the most from the Orders table. But when selecting worst-selling, I can't do the same, because those products may not be in the Orders table at all.

Comment: @aximili: So how do you want to get something what **does not exists at all**?

Comment: The product does exist in the products table just not the orders table and what they are saying is a valid point. The answer we all provided won't return products that were never sold even though they are technically the worst selling products. They may also be the newest products though. Just something to keep in mind that a product added two days ago that hasn't sold isn't necessarily a deadbeat product.

Answer (score 1):

Just change `OrderByDescending` to `OrderBy` and it should order them in ascending order.

Comment: It won't get products that are never ordered.

Comment: The best solution I can think of in LINQ would be to select from orders and products separately and select products that either don't exist in orders or order quantity is below a certain threshold and then select your top (or rather bottom) 10.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need a left outer join from Products to OrderedItems. `productsQty` should contain a list of Products with Qty from OrderedItems or 0 if there was none.

```
var productQty = from p in Products
            join oi in OrderedItems on p equals oi.Product into joined
            from poi in joined.DefaultIfEmpty()
            select new { Product = p, Qty = poi == null ? 0 : poi.Qty };
var products = productQty.GroupBy(p => p.Product).OrderBy(g => g.Sum(oi => oi.Qty)).Take(10);
```

UPDATE: Query corrected.

Comment: Your query performs an inner join and will therefore exclude products that aren't in any orderedItems.

Comment: @RiskyMartin You're right, thanks a lot for pointing that out. I should have tested the query before posting.